# Not letting user change cookies arbitrarily

Tags: cookies, client, backend

I want to implement a site with little to no database. I want to store users' profiles and preferences and clearance levels in cookies instead of databases. I want to only store username and password in the database.
The problem is that users can manipulate cookies at their will and gain unwanted privileges. How could I solve this security issue?
I was thinking of a kind of nonce in cookies but I don't know the exact details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are stored on the client. The user can therefore change them if they want to.

Please refer to this link :
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140217/cant-a-user-change-his-session-information-to-impersonate-others